# How to change color of keywords in vs code (setting.json)

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I want to change color of these words.

[image]

```
"[Monokai Dimmed]": {
    // https: //code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color
    // "editor.foreground" : "#ff0000",
    // "editorLineNumber.foreground" : ""
    // "????" : ""
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first you should backup the theme you want to make change in it so go to the path and copy all files.
for example we going to make change in theme-defaults

in Linux :

> "/opt/visual-studio-code/resources/app/extensions/THEME_YOU_WANT_TO_EDIT/themes/"

in windows:

> "C:\program files\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\extensions\THEME_YOU_WANT_TO_EDIT\themes"

in windows path can be different depends where you installed.

after backup

open your project with vscode and press **Ctrl+Shift+P** and search for

> ">Developer: Inspect Editor"[image]

and select part of the keyword you want to change the color of it.
in this one we going to change function color:[image]
now copy the style name
and open Json files with vscode you backup them before and search for style name in all files until you find it. click the little color icon and select color you want and save it. [image: i select red color]
unfortunately you can not see change with out reopening the vscode. so close vscode and open it again
[image]
as you can see color of function keyword changed.

Answer (score 3):

You may also override token-colors for each installed theme in your user- or workspace settings, without changing the original theme:

```json
// settings.json
// Color customizations
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "comments": "#c3c3c3",
        "variables": "#41c971",
        "keywords": "#95b7e9",
        "functions": "#f95dc5",
        "types": "#FF0000",
        "strings": "#c8da6b",
        "numbers": "#95ffd1",
    }
},
```

This works for all additional installed themes and the default ones.

Comment: Thanks! finally got the perfect solution. Everything works smoothly.

Comment: is there any documentation where you find these keys in the json like comments, variable, strings.. Though they are very common just checking if there is any document with screenshots?

Comment: Don't forget to update or remove the `"[Default Dark+]": {}` node, 'cos it won't change your theme unless it's "Default Dark+".